# DataTable Lento

Tags: c#

Boa Tarde, Galera

Tenho a rotina abaixo. Eu precisaria agilizar esta rotina ela demora muito para processar, alguém saberia me dizer como eu poderia fazer isso ?

O Select efetuado no DataSet dsParam pode trazer mais de 1 linha.

```
                    DataTable dtEndereco = new DataTable();

                    foreach (DataRow drEnd in dsParam.Tables["Endereco"].Select(string.Format("ID = {0} AND Documento = '{1}'", drNotas["ID"].ToString(), Documento)))
                    {
                        dtEndereco.ImportRow(drEnd);

                        dtEndereco.Rows[l]["ID"] = int.Parse(ID_Ini) * -1;
                        dtEndereco.Rows[l]["Documento"] = Documento_Ini;
                        l++;
                    }
```

Comment: Olá Marcos,
sua consulta retorna quantos registros?

Comment: Você já analisou se oque demora é a consulta pra gerar o DataTable ou o foreach? Se for a consulta precisará de mais detalhes do banco e da procedure que gera o DataTable.

Comment: É o Foreach, efetuei essa analise

Comment: @Marcosmuekita, então seu poblema está no Select do `DataSet` dsParam. Mas para te ajudar será necessário mais informações.

Comment: Quais informações vc precisa ? A solução que o Carlos me passou não solucionou a lentidão. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço

Answer (score -2):

tenta tirar do foreach a expression, algo assim:

```
    ...    

DataSet dsParam;
DataTable dt = dsParam.Tables["Endereco"];
DataRow[] rows;
string  expression = string.Format("ID = {0} AND Documento = '{1}'", drNotas["ID"].ToString(), Documento);

rows = table.Select(expression);
foreach (DataRow drEnd in rows)
{
   dtEndereco.ImportRow(drEnd);
   dtEndereco.Rows[l]["ID"] = int.Parse(ID_Ini) * -1;
   dtEndereco.Rows[l]["Documento"] = Documento_Ini;
   l++;
 }
```